# remote gui for ros applications

Tags: ros, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was wondering if there is something like a remote GUI applications can use? Something like a server on a desktop pc where clients can connect to and request to display a window with buttons and so on so the user can interact with the application without having to forward X?

regards jgdo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12297/remote-gui-for-ros-applications/) by [jgdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1517/jgdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have ROS installed on the other machine, you can use the graphical tools (rviz, rxgraph, etc) across your network: http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1